# How to open MDB personal geodatabase in JAVA

Tags: personal-geodatabase, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I'm trying to open a MDB personal geodatabase using the ArcGISSDK java10.2.4 doing the following:

```
String pathMDB="C:\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Pruebas\\OpenPersonalGeodatabaseMDB\\GDB_CI6_L01.mdb";
        Geodatabase mdbGeodatabase=null;
        try {
                mdbGeodatabase= new Geodatabase(pathMDB);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenPersonalGeodatabaseMDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

I get the error "File opened that is not a database file". I tried with two diferents files whith the same result. Is there another way to do it ?.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/129913 - I suspect that you may need to merge your GIS SE user accounts.

Comment: Yes, I asked to eliminate duplicate publication. Thx

Comment: MDB isn't a Geodatabase, we can't open the MDB with this class. The correct code is: [code]try {
            AccessWorkspaceFactory wsf = new AccessWorkspaceFactory();
            Workspace wspace = new Workspace(wsf.openFromFile(pathMDB, 0));[/code]. My actual problem is that i haven't a instalation of ArcGIS with all the libraries necesary to develop.

Comment: If your original question needs clarification please do that via the **edit** button beneath it because comments may not always be read by potential answerers.